# Properties of the Gaussian measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $\mu$ be a Gaussian measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(H)$. This means that there exist some $m \in H$ and a bounded linear operator $Q : H \rightarrow H$ (which is symmetric, non-negative definite and with finite trace) such that for every $h \in H$ the image measure of $\mu$ under the mapping
$$
H \ni g \mapsto h'(g) := \langle g, h\rangle
$$
is Gaussian on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, namely, $N(\langle m, h \rangle, \langle Qh, h \rangle )$.

I am interested in proving the following equalities:

> For all $f, h \in H$ we have
> $$
> \int_H \langle g, h \rangle \, \mu (dg) = \langle m, h \rangle, \tag{1}
> $$
> $$
> \int_H (\langle g, h \rangle - \langle m, h \rangle) (\langle g, f \rangle - \langle m, f \rangle) \, \mu (dg) = \langle Q f , h \rangle \tag{2}.
> $$

For $(1)$ we can use the transformation theorem and the fact that $\mu \circ (h')^{-1}$ is Gaussian with mean $\langle m, h \rangle$ to get
$$
\int_H \langle g, h \rangle \, \mu (dg) = \int_H h'(g) \, \mu (dg) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \, (\mu \circ (h')^{-1})(dx) = \langle m, h \rangle.
$$
Similarly, for $(2)$, if $f=h$, we can use the fact that $\mu \circ (h')^{-1}$ is Gaussian with variance $\langle Qh, h \rangle$ to get
$$
\int_H (\langle g, h \rangle - \langle m, h \rangle )^2 \, \mu (dg) = \int_H (h'(g) - \langle m, h \rangle)^2 \, \mu (dg) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (x - \langle m, h \rangle)^2 \, (\mu \circ (h')^{-1})(dx) = \langle Q h , h \rangle.
$$

---

But how can one show $(2)$ when $f \neq h$?